# The role of "of" in "we may speak of a vast, soulless corporation or describe an athlete as the soul of his team"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

The role of "of" in "we may speak **of** a vast, soulless corporation or describe an athlete as the soul of his team"

1. What is the role of the first "of" in the sentence above?
2. What's the difference between "speak of" and "speak about"?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's only a slight difference between "of" and "about", so you could use either one in this sentence.

Anyway, here's a link which explains that slight difference; read it, if you're interested:

https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/question/speak-of-vs-speak-about/